# Reemplazo de keys en array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, rest

Estoy subiendo una respuesta de una API que contiene formularios a una API propia, la cual desestructura el objecto recibido y solo retorna el objeto con las propiedades necesarias. El paso siguiente a esto es, esos valores de los keys, cambiarlos por algo más acorde a lo que necesito integrar en mi sistema.

Por ejemplo: 'Section_B_Demographic_Details' reemplazarlo con un espacio en blanco y que solo quede 'lugar_inscripción', y así con todos los que repita ese identificador.

Al recibir la respuesta de la ruta en la cual se encuentra dicho array, tengo lo siguiente:

```
{
"data": [
{
"formhub/uuid": "xxxxx",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/lugar_inscripcion": "xx",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/nombre_apellido": "xx",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/tipo_up": "xxx",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/nombre_up_emprend_negocio": "xxx",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/comienzo_activ_up": "xxx",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/calle_up": "xxx",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/altura_up": "xxx",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/dato_adic_ubicac_up": "xxx",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/comuna": "xx",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/barrio": "xxxx",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/email_up": "xxx",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/red_social_up": "xxx"
},
```

La respuesta es mucho más grande y tiene más de 200 registros, pero con fines de resolver la duda, basta con mostrar uno solo. Estuve intentando con varios ejemplos, como:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(
    (key) => (obj[key] === 'key del json') ? obj[key] = '-' : obj[key]
);
```

```
const jsonObj = JSON.stringify(obj,
    (key, value) => (value === key del json) ? '-' : value
);
```

y no logro dar con la resolución de reemplazar en todos los registros la coincidencia, solamente agarra la primera coincidencia y lo demás lo deja tal cual está.

Desde ya agradezco su ayuda y cualquier dato adicional que haga falta, si no está claro, también agradecería me informen para poder editar la publicación.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado o investigado? Dices que intentaste con varios ejemplos que encontraste, ¿puedes mostrar al menos uno? Haz clic en [edit] y agrega esos detalles. Te invito a leer [mre]. Saludos

Comment: Hola, gracias. Ahí modifiqué con algunos ejemplos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes lograr usando el método [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) de Array.

La idea es devolver un nuevo Array con los objetos cuyas claves han sido cambiadas.
Para cambiar los nombres de las propiedades debes recorrer cada objeto y cambiar el nombre de las propiedades que necesitas. Para reemplazar puedes usar el método [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) de String, y para recorrer el objeto puedes usar el bucle [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Por ejemplo:

```js
const replaceStringFromKeyName = (str, obj) => {
  const newObj = {};
  for(const propName in obj) {
    const newPropName = propName.replace(str, '');
    newObj[newPropName] = obj[propName];
  }
  return newObj;
}

const json = {
  "data": [
    {
      "formhub/uuid": "xxxxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/lugar_inscripcion": "xx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/nombre_apellido": "xx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/tipo_up": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/nombre_up_emprend_negocio": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/comienzo_activ_up": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/calle_up": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/altura_up": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/dato_adic_ubicac_up": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/comuna": "xx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/barrio": "xxxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/email_up": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/red_social_up": "xxx"
    }
  ]
};
const str = 'Section_B_Demographic_Details/';
const newData = json.data.map(obj => replaceStringFromKeyName(str, obj));

console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta tan rápido!! Solucionado.